First Synchronized has been running for 7 days and is at 82%
I have a raspberry pi 5 and the sync has been running for over a week and is only at 82%. Each process point takes longer. I have increased the memory usage to 6000 MB. How long does the first sync take today? BR
——
Ok, I understand there's not much I can do. It just take time. Does anyone know what the current average time is?

This question is similar to: Sync with bitcoin-qt very slow (0,01%). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also answers to other questions about raspberry pi synchronization such as this
